# Salvando dados em banco local com ionic

Tags: php, ionic

É possível salvar dados num banco de dados local, no meu computador, rodando o app no meu celular?
Exemplo, criei um app no ionic, onde cadastro nomes, e ao salvar, quero que ele salve no meu banco local do computador, usando php, é claro. É possível ou só se for um banco de dados em um domínio na web?

Valeu

Comment: É possível sim. Você teria que fazer uma API REST e coloca-la na rede local. Então o seu APP iria se comunicar com essa API

Comment: Precisa ser REST? Um simples código em php não rola?
Outra coisa, como vai direcionar os dados do celular pro PC?

Comment: Eu não entendo muito de PHP pra te dizer isso, mas acho que a melhor maneira de se comunicar com o angular é através de JSON, por isso você teria que ter uma API Rest